# Probability of choosing 5 out of 60 in ascending order.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, combinations

The title may be a little misleading. Let's say we choose 5 out of 60 balls. We write down the result which are in a form as $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5$.

> I have to calculate the probability of this happening :

\begin{aligned}k_1<k_2<k_3<k_4<k_5\end{aligned}

> Also, the probability of this happening:

\begin{aligned}k_1>\max\{k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5\}\end{aligned}

We do care for the order so the number of the elements in the sample space is : $$\frac{60!}{(60-5)!}$$
I am stuck there. I can't think of anything to do to calculate those two probabilities. I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there replacement?

Comment: I am not familiar with the english terminology, are you asking if the order matters? if that's it what you are asking then yes.

Comment: The question is are the balls put back after each selection?  Could $k_1=k_2$?

Comment: Is it possible to get the same ball twice ?

Comment: So, the answer is that this is not selected with replacement.

Comment: No, the balls aren't put back after selection!

Comment: not put back = not selected with replacement = selected without replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

Let the balls carry the numbers $1,2,\dots,60$

For the $5$ numbers on the balls that are drawn there are $5!$ orderings with equal probability and exactly one of them is an ascending order.

All $5$ drawn balls have equal chance to be labeled with the largest number.

Comment: In the 2nd one, do we have to take the probability of one of $k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5$ being bigger that the others (to get the max) and then again the probability of $k_1$ being larger from that number?

Comment: statement $k_1>\max\{k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5\}$ is exactly the same as the statement $k_1=\max\{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5\}$. So to be found is the probability that $k_1$ is the largest.

Comment: Doesn't $k_1$ have the same probability to be the largest as the other ones. But still, I can't get how we can calculate that...

Comment: Yes it has. If there are $5$ candidates all having the same probability to win, then the probability that candidate1 wins is $\frac15$. This is also true for the candidates 2,3,4,5 respectively. This because you have $5$ equal probabilities that add up to $1$.

Comment: You have been really helpful, thank you !

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: 'equal probability' Why? I think the probability depends on how the balls are drawn?

Comment: @BCLC We know how the balls are drawn: at random and without replacement. Have you any reason to believe that e.g. order $5,45,7,22,31$ is more or less likely to occur then the ascending order $5,7,22,31,45$?

Comment: @drhab Have you any reason to believe that they are equal? If I flip a coin is the probability of heads 1/2?

Comment: @BCLC Nothing special is said about the choosing. That is my reason to believe that the chances are equal. On your second question: yes, if the coin is fair.

Comment: @drhab So the answer is technically no?

Comment: @BCLC "Vanitas is my hardest opponent" is to be read on my profile. This discussion is purely in vain, so this is my last comment. Note that you asked $5$ questions by now, this without answering my question.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever $5$ (distinct) numbers wind up being chosen, they could have come out in any of $5!=120$ orders.  So the probability they came out in increasing order is $1/120$.

Comment: So, because all of the numbers have equal probability then the probability of $k_1 < \cdots k_5$ happening is $1/120$ ?

Comment: @George.K, yes, that's right.

Comment: And how about the other one. The same doesn't applie right?

Answer (score 1):

Each choice in which $k_1 < \cdots k_5$ corresponds one-to-one to a way to pick five balls from the set of 60. Prove this statement. Then think about how many ways there are to pick 5 balls from 60.

This should be easy. The second one is a little harder, but having thought about the first one in these terms should help. Please write back if you get stuck again.

Comment: There are $5!$ ways to get 5 out of 60, I get that . But, that doesn't specify how many ways are in order for the first inequality to be valid.

Comment: Mmm... no, there aren't. The phrase "60 choose 5" is related to this.

Comment: Wow, sorry I meant there are $5!$ ways to order the 5 taken balls.